# JSON and v-if troubles with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In the following example neither of the v-if related divs seem to get rendered before or after clicking the Add button. It seems like Vue.js isn't running any updates when the pizzas JSON object is updated.

Is there a solution to this problem without resorting to changing the pizzas variable into being an array?

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="pizza in pizzas">
    {{ pizza }}
  </div>
  <div v-if="totalPizzas === 0">
    No pizza. :(
  </div>
  <div v-if="totalPizzas > 0">
    Finally, some pizza! :D
  </div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pizzas: {}
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.pizzas['pepperoni'] = { size: 16, toppings: [ 'pepperoni', 'cheese' ] };
      this.pizzas['meaty madness'] = { size: 14, toppings: [ 'meatballs', 'sausage', 'cajun chicken', 'pepperoni' ] };
    },
    totalPizzas: function() {
      return Object.keys(this.pizzas).length;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to be improved in your code. Most of them are about syntax. For example, methods should be called, but computed properties can be queried directly: that's why it's `@click="add()"`, but `totalPizzas === 0` makes sense only if it's a computed property.

The crucial thing to understand, however, is [**how reactivity works in VueJS**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). See, while you change your object innards, adding new properties to it, this change is not detected by VueJS. Quoting the docs:

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive
> properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to
> add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` method:

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

> You can also use the `vm.$set` instance method, which is an alias to the
> global `Vue.set`:

```
this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

> Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing
> object, for example using `Object.assign()` or `_.extend()`. **However, new
> properties added to the object will not trigger changes.** In such
> cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original
> object and the mixin object:

```
// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

---

And this is how it might work:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pizzas: {}
  },
  computed: {
    totalPizzas: function() {
      return Object.keys(this.pizzas).length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.pizzas = Object.assign({}, this.pizzas, {
        pepperoni: { size: 16, toppings: [ 'pepperoni', 'cheese' ] },
        ['meaty madness']: { size: 14, toppings: [ 'meatballs', 'sausage', 'cajun chicken', 'pepperoni' ] }
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="pizza in pizzas">
    Size: {{ pizza.size }} inches
    Toppings: {{ pizza.toppings.join(' and ') }}
  </div>
  <div v-if="totalPizzas === 0">
    No pizza. :(
  </div>
  <div v-if="totalPizzas > 0">
    Finally, some pizza! :D
  </div>
  <button @click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```